# npx npm_config_yes=true or --yes not working as expected and npx still requires confirmation for installation

Tags: continuous-integration, npx, npm-cli

tried npm_config_yes=true
tried --yes
and I still get requires confirmation for installation
[image]

context:
$ npm -v
8.11.0
$ node -v
v16.15.1

Any workaround is appreciated also

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with npx,
`—-yes` wasn’t working but `-y` worked as expected.